# How many mobile app developers are there?

Tags: mobile

Does anyone have any statistics of how many iPhone/Android/RIM developers are out there?

Comment: That is not a programming question

Comment: Why do you require an answer to this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to accurately answer that question. Google-ing may give you a good idea though, for example [this page](http://www.appletell.com/apple/comment/ios-vs-android-what-side-are-developers-taking-or-are-they-taking-sides/)